# How to set IsEnabled property of stackpanel

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, radio-button, stackpanel

I am programtaically doing this part. I want to set the  UIElelemnts (radiobuttons) present on this stackpanel to partially visible so i want any equivalent property which can make the
stackpanel property IsEnabled set to  False (any quivalent property or any other way to achieve this because IsEnabled is not supported by stackpanel).

Or if it is possible to have another conntainer which could be parent of stackpanel and also supports IsEnabled property. (please do not suggest to set 
IsEnabled false for every radiobutton in loop when i set them on stackpanel because i cannot do this because of current situation in code i want some bigcontainer which can be
  set to IsEnabled).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to Wrap the stack panel with the content template and set it’s IsEnabled property to false.

```
<ContentControl IsEnabled="false">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="5">       
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="70"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="90"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <TextBlock Text="Fullname" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" />
            <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/>
            <TextBlock Text="Address" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"/>
            <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"/>
        </Grid>
        <Button Content="Update" Margin="5" Width="100"/>
    </StackPanel>
</ContentControl>
```

Comment: thajnsk for teh answer but please answer in c# programatically with explaination. I am a beginner.

Comment: Ok i know that i have already tried it ,suppose i have stackpanel "sp" and ContentControl "cc" now how to integrate them so that this cc will have sp as child ? because cc dont support children property so that i would be able to make sp as its children.

Comment: Content control has a content property, should be able to set cc.Content = sp; as per [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.content(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: i guess you can try with content property